# String to time stamp conversion

Tags: python, string, datetime, type-conversion, timestamp

I have a data file with about 5.6million time-stamps in the format "2016-10-17 15:00:40.739". They are all strings at the moment for some reason and I need to convert them all to date times as I will later need to calculate the difference between groups of them (e.g: stamp1 -> stamp2 = 2hours, 4minutes etc).

I found another question "[Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)" but mine are in a different format and I cannot get that answer to work for me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If your file is usual text file, there is no other way to store datetimes in it other than in strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy's `datetime64`:

```
>>> np.datetime64('2016-10-17 15:00:40.739')
numpy.datetime64('2016-10-17T15:00:40.739')
```

You can easily find differences by simply subtracting, or using numpy's `timedelta64`:

```
>>> np.datetime64('2016-10-17 15:00:40.739') - np.datetime64('2016-10-15 15:00:40.739')
numpy.timedelta64(172800000,'ms')
>>> np.datetime64('2016-10-17 15:00:40.739') + np.timedelta64(1,'D')
numpy.datetime64('2016-10-18T15:00:40.739')
```

Comment: This works and is a really simple solution but I'm getting this as the output: 2016-10-17T15:00:40.739. Any reason there's a T in there?

Comment: You can convert to a `datetime` format with `from datetime import datetime; numpy.datetime64('2016-10-19T15:00:40.739').astype(datetime)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = "2016-10-17 15:00:40.739"
b = datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(b)
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 17, 15, 0, 40, 739000)
```

To define the format of your dates. Follow this guide: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.1)** module to convert the string date to datetime object.

```
from dateutil import parser
dt =  parser.parse("2016-10-17 15:00:40.739")
print dt
print type(dt)
```

**Output:**

```
2016-10-17 15:00:40.739000
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```